# iOS - how to get music file from shared folder with use swift

Tags: ios, swift, shared-directory

I make a music player with swift. I want that an user adds music files via the shared folder in iTunes. I made the shared folder. How can I load files from the shared folder to `UITableViewCell` and then manage them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a following code. It works for me

```
        func exportFilesFromFolder() {
        var folder = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask).first as! NSURL
        var allFiles = fileManager.contentsOfDirectoryAtURL(folder, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: NSDirectoryEnumerationOptions.SkipsHiddenFiles, error: nil)!
        var filterArray = allFiles.map(){ $0.lastPathComponent }.filter(){ $0.pathExtension == "mp3" } as [String]
//        println("filter array \(allFiles[3])")
        var superURL: NSURL!
        for itemInFilterArray in filterArray {
            var direct = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask)
            if var url: NSURL = direct.first as? NSURL {
                superURL = url.URLByAppendingPathComponent(itemInFilterArray)
            }
            var playerItem = AVPlayerItem(URL: superURL)
            var equalazerString: String!
            var commonMetaData = playerItem.asset.commonMetadata as! [AVMetadataItem]
            for item in commonMetaData {
                if item.commonKey == "title" {
                    equalazerString = item.stringValue
                    if equalazerString == currentSongString {
                        localArrayNames.append(superURL)
                    } else {
//                        println("it is not equals")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```